# Why is Tails (2.5) Live O/S ignoring 'ExitNodes' in torrc?

Tags: configuration, tails, exit-relays

is this a possible unreported bug in the tor browser 6.0.3 on tails 2.5 live?
just for clarification, i experimented and added these commands:

> ExitNodes {CH}
>
> StrictNodes 1

either one by one or all at the same time to these files (to no avail):

> /usr/local/lib/tor-browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc
>
> /etc/tor/torrc
>
> /lib/live/mount/overlay/etc/tor/torrc

the tor browser simply doesnt pick up the new variables.

i should also add that setting ExitNodes dynamically at the command line:

> tor --ExitNodes "{CH}"

generates these messages:

> root@amnesia:/home/amnesia# tor --ExitNodes "{CH}"
>
> Aug 18 13:51:17.148 [notice] Tor v0.2.7.6 (git-605ae665009853bd) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.1k and Zlib 1.2.8.
>
> Aug 18 13:51:17.148 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
>
> Aug 18 13:51:17.151 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
>
> Aug 18 13:51:17.160 [warn] ControlPort is open, but no authentication method has been configured.  This means that any program on your computer can reconfigure your Tor.  That's bad!  You should upgrade your Tor controller as soon as possible.
>
> Aug 18 13:51:17.161 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
>
> Aug 18 13:51:17.161 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9050: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
>
> Aug 18 13:51:17.161 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9061
>
> Aug 18 13:51:17.162 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9061: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
>
> Aug 18 13:51:17.162 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9062
>
> Aug 18 13:51:17.162 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9062: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
>
> Aug 18 13:51:17.162 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
>
> Aug 18 13:51:17.162 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9150: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
>
> Aug 18 13:51:17.162 [notice] Opening DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5353
>
> Aug 18 13:51:17.162 [notice] Opening Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9040
>
> Aug 18 13:51:17.162 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9040: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
>
> Aug 18 13:51:17.162 [notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
>
> Aug 18 13:51:17.162 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9051: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
>
> Aug 18 13:51:17.162 [notice] Closing partially-constructed DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5353
>
> Aug 18 13:51:17.162 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
>
> Aug 18 13:51:17.162 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.

any ideas how to get around this problem?

Comment: Did you reload Tor after making the foolish changes?

Comment: well, no.  i didnt reload.  what i did was:

Comment: well, no.  i didnt reload.  what i did was: >sudo service tor stop; made changes via >echo .."etc" and then >sudo service tor restart;  that didnt work; however, after your suggestion to "reload"; that work.  and for that i thank you.  needless to say, the changes i incorporated are not "foolish"!  they are necessary as the site i access is using html5 canvas image extraction and geoip to "finger print" and id users for access.  i hope that takes the sting out of your critique.